# Clojure map anonymous function

Tags: clojure

I´m trying to map an anonymous function to a collection and I get a ClassCastException.

```
(defn mapanfn
  [names]
  (map (#(str "Hello %"))
       names))

(mapanfn ["Bobby" "Nico" "Ringo"])
```

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take out the extra set of parentheses around your anonymous function, and use `format` if you want to use a format specifier:

```
(defn mapanfn
  [names]
  (map #(format "Hello %s" %) names))
```

Or use `str` without a format specifier:

```
(defn mapanfn
  [names]
  (map #(str "Hello " %) names))
```

In both cases `%` is referring to the value your anonymous functions is called with, but it will not work *inside* a string.

Answer (score 1):

You made a couple of mistakes here.

The first one, the `%` symbol should not be a part of a string. Perhaps you confused it with the standard `format` function. So the expression should be either `(str "Hello " %)` or `(format "Hello %s" %)`.

The second one, you call your anonymous function twice because of extra parens. The `#(str "Hello %")` expression returns a function, but putting it into parens calls it once again and gives a string `"Hello %"`. So inside a `map` function, you are trying to call a string as a function, which is calling an Exception.

The right function in your example would be just `#(str "Hello " %)`.